# Evolutionary Algorithm for the Theo Jansen Walking Mechanism

Tags: python, math, geometry, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

There is a Dutch artist/engineer who created a very elaborate walking mechanism. The working principle can be seen here:

http://www.strandbeest.com/beests_leg.php

The curious part is that he used a self-made Evolutionary Algorithm to calculate the ideal link lengths, which are described at the bottom of the page.

I created a Python script to visually analyze the ground-contact part of the cycle, which must have two requisites fulfilled:

1. Be as straight as possible, so as not to wobble up and down;
2. Have a speed as constant as possible, so as not to drag one foot against the other;

These two criteria would result in a "wheel like" effect, with the machine going linearly ahead without wasting kinetic energy.

The question is:

"Do you  have any suggestion of a simple evolutionary iterative formula to optimize leg lengths (by inserting the correct mutations in the code below) so as to improve the walking path given the two criteria above?"

EDIT: some suggestions about the "fitting rule" for genome candidates:

- Take the "lower part" (ground contact) of the cycle, given that it corresponds to one third of crank revolution (mind the lower part might have a non-horizontal slope and still be linear);
- Apply linear regression on the point positions of this "ground contact" part;
- Calculate vertical variation from the linear regression (least squares?)
- Calculate speed variation by the difference between one point and the previous one, parallel to the regression line;
- (optional) plot graphs of these "error functions", possibly allowing to select mutants visually (boooring... ;o).

Here is my code, in Python + GTK, which gives some visual insight into the problem:
(EDIT: now with parametrized magic numbers subject to mutation by `mut`'s values)

```
# coding: utf-8

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk, cairo
from math import *

class Mechanism():
    def __init__(s):
        pass

    def assemble(s, angle):

        # magic numbers (unmutated)
        mu = [38, 7.8, 15, 50, 41.5, 39.3, 61.9, 55.8, 40.1, 39.4, 36.7, 65.7, 49]

        # mutations
        mut = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

        # mutated
        mn = [mu[n]+mut[n] for n in range(13)]

        s.A = Point(0,0)
        s.B = Point(-mn[0], -mn[1])

        s.C = fromPoint(s.A, mn[2], angle)
        s.ac = Line(s.A, s.C)

        s.D = linkage(s.C, mn[3], s.B, mn[4])
        s.cd = Line(s.C, s.D)
        s.bd = Line(s.B, s.D)

        s.E = linkage(s.B, mn[5], s.C, mn[6])
        s.be = Line(s.B, s.E)
        s.ce = Line(s.C, s.E)

        s.F = linkage(s.D, mn[7], s.B, mn[8])
        s.df = Line(s.D, s.F)
        s.bf = Line(s.B, s.F)

        s.G = linkage(s.F, mn[9], s.E, mn[10])
        s.fg = Line(s.F, s.G)
        s.eg = Line(s.E, s.G)

        s.H = linkage(s.G, mn[11], s.E, mn[12])
        s.gh = Line(s.G, s.H)
        s.EH = Line(s.E, s.H)


        return s.H


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = float(x), float(y)
    def __str__(self):
        return "(%.2f, %.2f)" % (self.x, self.y)

class Line:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1, self.p2 = p1, p2
    def length(self):
        return sqrt((p1.x-p2.x)**2 + (p1.y-p2.y)**2)

def fromPoint(point, distance, angle):
    angle = radians(angle)
    return Point(point.x + distance * cos(angle),
        point.y + distance * sin(angle))

def distance(p1, p2):
    return sqrt( (p1.x - p2.x)**2 + (p1.y - p2.y)**2 )

def ccw(p1, p2, px):
    """ Test if px is at the right side of the line p1p2 """
    ax, ay, bx, by = p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y
    cx, cy = px.x, px.y
    return (bx-ax)*(cy-ay)-(by-ay)*(cx-ax) < 0

def linkage(p1, l1, p2, l2):
    l1 = float(l1)
    l2 = float(l2)
    dx,dy = p2.x-p1.x, p2.y-p1.y
    d = sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)                             # distance between the centers
    a = (l1**2 - l2**2 + d**2) / (2*d)                  # distance from first center to the radical line
    M = Point(p1.x + (dx * a/d), p1.y + (dy * a/d))     # intersection of centerline with radical line
    h = sqrt(l1**2 - a**2)                              # distance from the midline to any of the points
    rx,ry = -dy*(h/d), dx*(h/d)
    # There are two results, but only one (the correct side of the line) must be chosen
    R1 = Point(M.x + rx, M.y + ry)
    R2 = Point(M.x - rx, M.y - ry)
    test1 = ccw(p1, p2, R1)
    test2 = ccw(p1, p2, R2)
    if test1:
        return R1
    else:
        return R2




###############################33

mec = Mechanism()
stepcurve = [mec.assemble(p) for p in xrange(360)]

window=gtk.Window()
panel = gtk.VBox()
window.add(panel)
toppanel = gtk.HBox()
panel.pack_start(toppanel)

class Canvas(gtk.DrawingArea):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.DrawingArea.__init__(self)
        self.connect("expose_event", self.expose)

    def expose(self, widget, event):
        cr = widget.window.cairo_create()
        rect = self.get_allocation()
        w = rect.width
        h = rect.height
        cr.translate(w*0.85, h*0.3)
        scale = 1
        cr.scale(scale, -scale)
        cr.set_line_width(1)

        def paintpoint(p):
            cr.arc(p.x, p.y, 1.2, 0, 2*pi)
            cr.set_source_rgb(1,1,1)
            cr.fill_preserve()
            cr.set_source_rgb(0,0,0)
            cr.stroke()

        def paintline(l):
            cr.move_to(l.p1.x, l.p1.y)
            cr.line_to(l.p2.x, l.p2.y)
            cr.stroke()

        for i in mec.__dict__:
            if mec.__dict__[i].__class__.__name__ == 'Line':
                paintline(mec.__dict__[i])

        for i in mec.__dict__:
            if mec.__dict__[i].__class__.__name__ == 'Point':
                paintpoint(mec.__dict__[i])

        cr.move_to(stepcurve[0].x, stepcurve[0].y)
        for p in stepcurve[1:]:
            cr.line_to(p.x, p.y)
        cr.close_path()
        cr.set_source_rgb(1,0,0)
        cr.set_line_join(cairo.LINE_JOIN_ROUND)
        cr.stroke()

class FootPath(gtk.DrawingArea):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.DrawingArea.__init__(self)
        self.connect("expose_event", self.expose)

    def expose(self, widget, event):
        cr = widget.window.cairo_create()
        rect = self.get_allocation()
        w = rect.width
        h = rect.height

        cr.save()
        cr.translate(w/2, h/2)

        scale = 20
        cr.scale(scale, -scale)

        cr.translate(40,92)

        twocurves = stepcurve.extend(stepcurve)

        cstart = 305
        cr.set_source_rgb(0,0.5,0)
        for p in stepcurve[cstart:cstart+121]:
            cr.arc(p.x, p.y, 0.1, 0, 2*pi)
            cr.fill()

        cr.move_to(stepcurve[cstart].x, stepcurve[cstart].y)
        for p in stepcurve[cstart+1:cstart+121]:
            cr.line_to(p.x, p.y)
        cr.set_line_join(cairo.LINE_JOIN_ROUND)
        cr.restore()
        cr.set_source_rgb(1,0,0)
        cr.set_line_width(1)
        cr.stroke()




        cr.save()
        cr.translate(w/2, h/2)
        scale = 20
        cr.scale(scale, -scale)
        cr.translate(40,92)

        cr.move_to(stepcurve[cstart+120].x, stepcurve[cstart+120].y)
        for p in stepcurve[cstart+120+1:cstart+360+1]:
            cr.line_to(p.x, p.y)
        cr.restore()
        cr.set_source_rgb(0,0,1)
        cr.set_line_width(1)
        cr.stroke()



canvas = Canvas()
canvas.set_size_request(140,150)
toppanel.pack_start(canvas, False, False)

toppanel.pack_start(gtk.VSeparator(), False, False)

footpath = FootPath()
footpath.set_size_request(1000,-1)
toppanel.pack_start(footpath, True, True)


def changeangle(par):
    mec.assemble(par.get_value()-60)
    canvas.queue_draw()
angleadjust = gtk.Adjustment(value=0, lower=0, upper=360, step_incr=1)
angleScale = gtk.HScale(adjustment=angleadjust)
angleScale.set_value_pos(gtk.POS_LEFT)
angleScale.connect("value-changed", changeangle)
panel.pack_start(angleScale, False, False)


window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: This is an excellent question, but needs a lot of thought! In the mean time, I took the liberty of translating your code into Javascript, so that other contributors to Stack Overflow can experiment with this wonderful mechanism:  http://garethrees.org/2011/07/04/strandbeest/strandbeest.html

Comment: Great work, @Gareth Rees! I will update my question soon, so as to include some thoughts I had on the subject. Only one observation: I think the point E and F are swapped on your javascript model. Also, the working mechanism is composed of three mechanisms per "animal limb", with a 120 degree phase difference among them (the animation of three simultaneous limbs is pretty creepy!). Many thanks for your contribution!!

Comment: The labels on my model are the same as in your code (I transformed it fairly mechanically). The number of mechanisms needed is a function of the amount of time the leg spends on the ground. For example, the [Klann linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klann_linkage) spends half its time on the ground, so only needs two mechanisms per limb.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Try the demo!](http://garethrees.org/2011/07/04/strandbeest/strandbeest.html)

[image]

This is a fascinating question, though I think somewhat beyond the scope of Stack Overflow: it's not something that going to be solved in a few minutes, so I'll stick an outline here and update it if I make any progress. There are going to be three parts to any approach:

1. Scoring the footprint: does the linkage break? does the footprint have the right kind of shape? how flat is it? how smooth is the motion? does it spend enough time in the flat portion?
2. Searching for good values of the magic numbers. It's not clear that this has to be an evolutionary algorithm (though I can see why the idea of such an algorithm would appeal to Theo Jansen as it fits in with the animal metaphor in his art); perhaps other approaches like local search (hill climbing) or simulated annealing would be productive.
3. Searching for good configurations of the arms. This is where an evolutionary approach seems like it might be most worthwhile.

You can try out different magic numbers in my Javascript/canvas demo to see what kinds of motion you can get (CD = 55.4 is quite entertaining, for example). There's a whole [mathematical theory of linkages](http://www.math.toronto.edu/~drorbn/People/Eldar/thesis/default.htm), by the way, that connects the configuration spaces of linkages to topological manifolds.

---

I added some simple scoring to the demo. The *ground score* is the fraction of the cycle that the foot spends on the ground, which I take to be all points whose y-coordinate is within some tolerance of the lowest point. The *drag score* is the biggest difference between any two horizontal velocities while the foot is on the ground. (It's always negative, so that higher values = small differences in velocities = better.)

But here's where the difficulty comes in. In order to program any kind of search, I need to be able to combine these scores. But how do I balance them against each other? The Jansen magic numbers give me groundScore: 0.520; dragScore: -0.285. If I set AC=10, GH=65, EH=50, i get groundScore: 0.688; dragScore: -0.661. Nearly 70% of the time the foot is on the ground. But the take-off is draggy. Is it better or worse than Jansen's?

I think that getting actual engineering feedback in order to determine a good score is going to be the big problem here, not the actual search.

Comment: The parametrized version of your applet is great! When I get some graphics for the fitting error, I will update my code!

Comment: You did a great job introducing the scores, Gareth! As a suggestion, I would try to test horizontal displacement instead of speeds, since the result would come in the same length units used to build the linkage. Also, we must be aware that some combinations change the slope of the ground-contact path, so the points pertaining to this path should be within the tolerance distance from the double-tangent (if the path has some concave section) or minimum-curvature-tangent (if the path is fully convex) line. Indeed a very tricky problem...

Comment: I decided that (at least for now) I would assume that the ground-contact path is horizontal, because given any beest with a non-horizontal ground-contact path we can make appropriate changes to `Bx` and `By` to make it horizontal again. So restricting ourselves to horizontal footprints doesn't affect the space of beests we can analyze. (It might make the local search a bit less effective, but that can be looked at later.)

Comment: Can you expand on your point about displacement? (I understand the scaling issue—we don't want to get a better score just by shrinking the beest—but I don't understand what it would mean to "test horizontal displacement", or why this would help. I think the way to solve the scaling issue is to divide the drag score by some characteristic length, e.g. the length of the contact patch. Or is this what you mean?)

Comment: Actually speed and displacement are related to each other through time, so I thought removing the time factor (by using displacement instead of speed) would be perhaps more universal. Also, analysing sloped-ground-contact beests by compensating slope first-hand would be more effective, for it would be avoided to give a low score to a beest which have a straight but sloped path. I'll keep thinking! Thanks for your interest!

Comment: @Gareth Rees & @heltonbiker,  you guys are my software heros for that demo.  Your code makes it very clear on how to use Sylvester to do Vector analysis within Canvas on the browser.  One can model a wide variety of mechanisms.  ref: `http://dogfeatherdesign.com/engineering-projects/mechanisms-mechanical-walker/` Many thanks!

Comment: @zipzit Your 8-link walker made my day... It's an impressive research and sharing you've done, on this fascinating but rather understated topic of mechanisms! :D